# Postman Mock API Server - how to make it private after I already created the collection and made it public

Tags: postman, postman-mocks, postman-mock-api-server

As in the title. I have scoured the Postman documentation and went through different nooks and crannies in Postman desktop app but I am unable to make my mock api server private.

I have generated a Postman API Key and I am passing it with all the requests in mock api as **x-api-key** header but it doesn't change anything. I can still access the collection's endpoints by simply pasting the url in the browser.

When I was creating the mock api server, I choose public option to speed up the setup but now would like to make it private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Mock has already be created as a `Public` Server, you can make it `Private` by editing the Mock from the Collection menu in the app.

- Press the `>` option on the Collection name
- Select the `Mocks` tab
- Select the `Pencil` icon to `Edit` the Mock Server
- Check the *Make this mock server private* box
- Press the *Save Changes* button

Once this has been changed to a `Private` Server, you should be able to call it only using the `x-api-key` token in the header.

[image: Postman]

More details can be found on the Postman Learning Center:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock/#editing-mock-servers